# Running web.xml from Eclipse results in HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm working on Windows 7 with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers , and Tomcat 7 .

The hierarchy of my project is :

[image]

When I run the following web.xml , meaning I hit CTRL+F11 from within Eclipse the following web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LoginExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I get this :

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what causes this , any idea anyone ?

Here is index.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
                                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="LoginServlet">

            Please enter your username      
            <input type="text" name="un"/><br>      

            Please enter your password
            <input type="text" name="pw"/>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">            

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WEB-INF` is a protected folder, servlet container (Tomcat in your case) won't allow you to access it. It would be quite bad if anybody could take a look on your web application settings (especially the security ones). Just go to the `localhost:8080/LoginExample/index.jsp`, then you can see your page.

Comment: OK ,any suggestion what to do then ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the the **WEB-INF** directory or any of its contents directly from a web application.

If you want to access the **index.jsp** page, just open the URL `http://localhost:8080/LoginExample` and the web server would forward you to the **index.jsp** (as specified in the web.xml)

Or you can always access the page directly using its full path as in `http://localhost:8080/LoginExample/index.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the path, instead of /WEB-INF/web.xml to /index.jsp, if this does not work try to resolve it, with servlet maping,something like this [Servlet JSP web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401588/servlet-jsp-web-xml).