# JSP content is coming as text on browser in JBOSS

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, jboss7.x

Problem is that JBoss is not processing JSP in my project.
After deploying WAR, When I access JSP, its complete content (as text) is appearing in the browser. Below is my `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.qn.sampleJboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-boot-jboss</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin> </plugins> -->

        <plugins

            <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <warName>sample-boot</warName> <outputDirectory>C:\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\deployments</outputDirectory> 
                </configuration> </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You need to register JSP as a serlet, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401588/servlet-jsp-web-xml

Comment: or a servlet even :)